# href to an element in the same page in HTML Mail

Tags: html, email, hyperlink

Im trying to add a link to an element in the same page:

```
    <a href="#someElement">
         .
         .
         .  
    <div id="someElement">
```

which works fine. but when the page is being send in mail message, the link is being open in a new tab in the browser, and doesn't simply jump to the element in the html mail message.
I tried with the quotes (of the id name) and without. I tried to give a full path to the element, nothing works.

any suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: try `<a href="#someElement" target="_self">`

Comment: Can you try putting target = "_self" in the anchor tag and see if that works?

Comment: Inherently depends on which mail client the recipient is using. Thus, not a programming question; voting to close.

Comment: I tried on gmail, gmail app on iphone, hotmail, outlook, I don't think its the client as all client behave the same here. don't you agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anchor

```
<a href="#someElement">Link to your element</a>
```

to link to id

```
<div id="someElement">
```

or name

```
<a name="someElement">...</a>
```

it's possible but not working everywhere http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3322/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/

Comment: no, still doesn't work. It works fine in the web page, but when im sending the page as html (Ctrl+c to the page into the mail message and send it to a client), the link is being open in a new tab in chrome. what im doing wrong?

Comment: @adiohaion look at this : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3322/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/